# "CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER" config is not work in django settings

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I set `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"` in my django project settings file. But It doesn't seem to work.

I check the celerybeat logs and I found that the celery beat scheduler is `celery.beat.PersistentScheduler`. I can only set  beat scheduler to "DatabaseScheduler" at the celery beat startup file (`celery -A config beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`).

How can I set the scheduler in django settings file ? I don't want to set the scheduler in the celery beat startup command.

Comment: celery version 4.4.0

django-celery-beat version 2.0.0

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following option to Django settings.py

For celery =< 4.4.0:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

For celery > 4.4.0:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

Comment: This is what worked for me: `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER`